# What is the code for selecting the top n integers from a list in Latex inside an algorithm?

Tags: pdftex, overleaf

> My list is l[] with 1000 integers. In the algorithm i am selecting top n integers from this list. How do i write the latex code for doing this.

can i use argmax operator for selecting maximum k values from the list or their corresponding indices ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to tex.sx. Please provide information about, what you have tried so far. In general, the ifthenelse-package does the job. In general, TeX isn't python and you shouldn't use it like that. If you will highly reuse this function, then writing it might be a good idea, if it is a one time use, it isn't worth it at all.

Comment: Pleease tell us whether you have to use pdflatex or if you're ok with using lualatex. The reason I ask is that you set the "pdftex" tag.

Comment: i am working with overleaf for writing my script which use pdflatex. further my algorithm simply selects a maximum 10 integers from a list . ifthenelse package would not work in my opinion. i am trying with for loop but it is not looking proper. how do i write it in single line with using argmax operator

Comment: You asked, "how do i write it in single line with using argmax operator"? You may be harboring some incorrect expectations as to what pdflatex is designed to do. LaTeX is primarily a typesetting system, *not* a general compuational engine.

Comment: it has not to use argmax, but simply latex code to select k maximum integers from a list of n elements

Comment: @honolulu but you have not said what you mean by list. do you have `{a}{b}{c}`  or `a,b,c` or `\item a \item b \item c`  or ... ? really your qustion gives no information at all about your input or required output. What is `l[]` ?

Comment: its a simple list , i have just specified it as L in the beginning of the algorithm...

Answer (score 2):

The solution based only on TeX primitives and basic Plain TeX macros is here:

```
\newcount\selected  

\def\alist{}
\def\scanlist#1 {%
   \ifx;#1\else
      \addtoalist\alist{#1}%
      \ifnum\selected>0 \advance\selected by-1
      \else \remlast\alist \fi
      \expandafter\scanlist
   \fi 
}
\def\remlast#1{\edef#1{\expandafter}\expandafter\remlastA#1{} }   
\def\remlastA #1 #2 {%
   \if^#2^\else
      \edef\alist{\alist#1 }\afterfi{\remlastA #2 }%
   \fi
}
\def\addtoalist#1#2{\def\tmp{#2}\edef#1{\expandafter}\expandafter\addtoalistA#1; }
\def\addtoalistA #1 {%
   \ifx;#1\edef\alist{\alist \tmp\space}\else
      \ifnum\tmp>#1 \edef\alist{\alist\tmp\space#1 }%
         \afterfi{\afterfi{\addtoalistB}}%
      \else \edef\alist{\alist #1 }%
         \afterfi{\afterfi{\addtoalistA}}%
      \fi
   \fi
}
\def\addtoalistB#1; {\edef\alist{\alist#1}}
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}

%% test:

\def\list{12 18 32 127 123 432 456 456 890 543 654 234 12 18 87 96 } 
\selected=5 % number of selected numbers

\expandafter\scanlist\list; % does the job, result is in \alist

\meaning\alist % macro-> 800 654 543 456 456

\bye
```

Comment: +1, even though the OP apparently requires the code to consist of a single line... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that you're using the `pdftex` tag, but just in case, here is a solution with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\directlua{
    function sortf(x, y)
        return x > y
    end

    function maxlist(L, n)
        table.sort(L, sortf)
        local M = {}
        for i = 1, n do
            M[i] = L[i]
        end
        return M
    end

    a = {1, 3, 2, 7, 4, 0}
    n = 3
}

\begin{document}
The list is \directlua{tex.print(a)} and its \directlua{tex.print(n)} biggest elements are \directlua{tex.print(maxlist(a, n))}.

\end{document}
```

In a nutshell:

- You can insert Lua code anywhere in LaTeX in `\directlua` commands.
- All `\directlua` blocks are "linked" so you can reuse content from one to the next.
- The `tex.print` function is necessary for Lua to send results to LaTeX.

The way I sorted the array to extract the biggest elements isn't the most elegant approach, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that selects the *n* largest integers from a comma-separated list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\listmax}{mm}{ % #1: list, #2: n
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpb_clist {#1}
    \clist_sort:Nn \l_tmpb_clist
      { \int_compare:nTF { ##1 < ##2 } { \sort_return_swapped: } { \sort_return_same: } }
    \clist_clear:N \l_tmpa_clist
    \int_step_inline:nn { #2 } { \clist_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\clist_item:Nn \l_tmpb_clist { ##1 }} }
    \clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {,~}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\listmax{2,11,13,8,4,1,3,5,7,9,20,6,101}{10}

\listmax{1,6,4,7,8,9}{4}
\end{document}
```